# In a bash script, how do I get the result of this $targetDir | tr '&' '+' into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

This is a very simple question.
It requires a very simple answer.
I'd rather not be referred to a book-length, overly general answer.

I want to replace all occurrences of & with + and put the value back into $targetDir

```
targetDir="&&&&&"
echo $targetDir # &&&&&

$targetDir=$targetDir | tr '&' '+' # *How do I actually make this happen?

echo $targetDir # +++++
```

Comment: `targetDir=$(echo "$targetDir" | tr ...)` -- note no `$` on the left-hand side; this isn't perl. `$` is an expansion operator, not part of the actual variable name.

Comment: That said, `targetDir=${targetDir//'&'/+}` is the faster/more efficient way to write this operation.

Comment: And use `echo "$targetDir"`, not `echo $targetDir` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: (even better would be replacing `echo "$targetDir"` with `printf '%s\n' "$targetDir"`; that way it'll work correctly in corner cases like `targetDir=-n`, and regardless of shell configuration when the directory name contains a backslash literal; see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) on [unix.se]; note in particular the parts talking about the `xpg_echo` flag in bash, and see the APPLICATION USAGE notes in the [POSIX `echo` standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in bash you don't need echo, just `targetDir=$(<<<$targetDir tr ...)`

Comment: @phuclv, indeed. That said, with all but the very latest versions of bash, heredocs and herestrings create a temporary file; that might not be desirable.

Comment: @phuclv, right, that's why I said "all but the very latest versions".